# How to properly set-up static IPv6 on CentOS 7.7

Tags: centos7, ipv6

I'm having a strange issue when trying to set-up a static IPv6 address on a dedicated CentOS 7.7 server. I'm able to ping the gateway sometimes, but every time I restart the network (using **systemctl restart network**) or reboot the server, the connection is lost. I'm not sure if the issue is on the server or with my server provider.

I couldn't fix the issue with NetworkManager, so I disabled it to only use the **/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-em1** file and have been using the **ip** command to play around with routes.

The content of the **ifcfg-em1** file related to the IPv6 settings is:

```
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6ADDR=2604:4300:a:289::2/64
IPV6_DEFAULTGW=2604:4300:a:289::1
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
```

I have also tried these settings (without any luck):

```
IPV6_PRIVACY=no
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
```

The results of **ip -6 a** is:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: em1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 2604:4300:a:289::2/64 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::2a0:d1ff:feec:aa4c/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Output when pinging the gateway:

```
PING 2604:4300:a:289::1(2604:4300:a:289::1) from 2604:4300:a:289::2 em1: 56 data bytes
From 2604:4300:a:289::2 icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
From 2604:4300:a:289::2 icmp_seq=2 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
From 2604:4300:a:289::2 icmp_seq=3 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
```

The routing table is:

```
::/96                          ::                         !n   1024 0      0 lo
0.0.0.0/96                     ::                         !n   1024 0      0 lo
2002:a00::/24                  ::                         !n   1024 0      0 lo
2002:7f00::/24                 ::                         !n   1024 0      0 lo
2002:a9fe::/32                 ::                         !n   1024 0      0 lo
2002:ac10::/28                 ::                         !n   1024 0      0 lo
2002:c0a8::/32                 ::                         !n   1024 0      0 lo
2002:e000::/19                 ::                         !n   1024 0      0 lo
2604:4300:a:289::/64           ::                         U    256 5     11 em1
3ffe:ffff::/32                 ::                         !n   1024 0      0 lo
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 0      0 em1
::/0                           2604:4300:a:289::1         UG   1   4      6 em1
::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1    223 lo
::1/128                        ::                         Un   0   3      9 lo
2604:4300:a:289::2/128         ::                         Un   0   4     39 lo
fe80::2a0:d1ff:feec:aa4c/128   ::                         Un   0   1      0 lo
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 8     82 em1
::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1    223 lo
```

Output from **ip -6 route**:

```
unreachable ::/96 dev lo metric 1024 error -113 pref medium
unreachable ::ffff:0.0.0.0/96 dev lo metric 1024 error -113 pref medium
unreachable 2002:a00::/24 dev lo metric 1024 error -113 pref medium
unreachable 2002:7f00::/24 dev lo metric 1024 error -113 pref medium
unreachable 2002:a9fe::/32 dev lo metric 1024 error -113 pref medium
unreachable 2002:ac10::/28 dev lo metric 1024 error -113 pref medium
unreachable 2002:c0a8::/32 dev lo metric 1024 error -113 pref medium
unreachable 2002:e000::/19 dev lo metric 1024 error -113 pref medium
2604:4300:a:289::/64 dev em1 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
unreachable 3ffe:ffff::/32 dev lo metric 1024 error -113 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev em1 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
default via 2604:4300:a:289::1 dev em1 metric 1 pref medium
```

I am not sure where all these routes are coming from and if they should all be there. I tried to remove everything but the the default route, but still no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your interface and routing table look fine. The routes you see are mostly for blocking traffic to invalid addresses. From the destination unreachable output I would say that IPv6 neighbor discovery (same function as ARP in IPv4) is failing. Do you have firewall rules blocking ICMPv6? That will break many things, including neighbor discovery.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I am not an expert when it comes to networking, especially not IPv6, so this was a healthy exercise for me. I actually don't have a firewall activated yet, just so that I could make sure the issue wasn't with the firewall. After pressuring my server provider they admitted something was wrong on their end and finally fixed the problem. It seems to be working OK now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After pressuring my server provider they admitted something was wrong on their end and finally fixed the problem. It seems to be working OK now.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `ONBOOT=yes` to the config file.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/sec-configuring_ip_networking_with_ifcg_files

Comment: Sorry for leaving that part out. The onboot=yes is actually already in the config.